# Is there a way have sheets auto populate data based on date and time

Tags: google-sheets, autocomplete

I have a team that is manually confirming tickets and use a sheet to organize the info. There are pre-made barcodes in the sheet that we are assigning orders to but our system won't allow us to manually input the same seating information for the same show. ie. For the showtime 5/25/21 6pm we can only have one ticket with row 1 seat 1.

Because we have to do this manually we find ourselves unsure which rows or seats have already been used out of the 100 possibilities. Rows 1 - 10 and seats 1 - 10.

I want to be able to input the showtime in sheets and a formula can give me the next open row/seat combination. So the formula reads the date/time input and reads the row/seat combinations for that same date/time within the sheet and gives a number 1-10 for row and 1-10 for seat based of the ones that have already been used.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wHxxmgYZG7hYnhpDcBrUnhICW27nwMf5xnPy92Dp4mE/edit#gid=0) is an example sheet with barcodes and a couple lines of data to get a (hopefully) better view of what I'm asking.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you asked but I believe it addresses the core of your issue (*we find ourselves unsure which rows or seats have already been used*).

1. Count the occurrence of that date/seat/row combination. You could do this by combining all three into a string representing a unique ID.
2. If count is greater than 1 then indicate False in an available column

In code this would look something like:

**`id` column**

```
=D2&"_"&E2&"_"&F2
```

Where columns D, E, and F represent date, row, and seat columns.

**`available?` column**

```
=IF(COUNTIF(K2:K9,K2)>1,"not available","available")
```

Where column K is your `id` column.

Apply those two across the entire column and as long as the dates are entered in the same format each time the `available?` column will immediately tell you if that seat/row is taken for the event date.

Comment: I believe this may work for the moment. I will test this out momentarily and accept your answer if it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's [an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1JCpSzMKiwMSdmfL2zSnJL4L8ALumONdc3PSIB9fZk) that does what you are looking for.

It applies the database function **DMAX** to the set of previous ticket sales (which is called the database). Here, DMAX filters the database to find only those records that match the same *Show* as you have entered in column D, and then finds the highest numbered row/seat combination, and returns to you the next possible row/seat combination in the green columns.

NB: This will always return the next higher seat. If you have left gaps in the seating order when assigning previous seats, it will ignore those and still assign the next seat after the highest previously assigned seat.

I have set conditional formatting on column D for convenience while developing this. It helps to visually find shows with the same date and time in the database. you can remove this using the "Format: Conditional Formatting" on the menu bar.

Comment: @kirkg13 Thank you! I thought I had set sharing correctly, but had missed one click. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Nice, elegant solution, James - creative use of the database functions, and how you chose to merge the row/seat data!

Answer (score 0):

I've got something that may work for you.
Have a look at the updated Fullfillment-GK tab in your sheet.
It's a bit messy, but could be cleaned up a lot if it is going in the right direction.

The key formula in K1 is:

```
={"Sorted Available Seats";
   QUERY(
     SORT(
       {FILTER(
         M2:M,ISERROR(MATCH(M2:M,L2:L,0))),
         SPLIT(FILTER(M2:M,ISERROR(MATCH(M2:M,L2:L,0))),"~",0,0)},
       3,1,4,1),
     "SELECT Col1",0)}
```

The steps are as follows.

1. All of your performance dates are entered and used as a named range, PerformanceDates.  See column P.
2. All possible Row and Seat combinations (1-1,1-2,...,10-10) are listed as a named range, AllRowSeats.  See column O.
3. The agent/user selects a desired date in the lookup box.
   Intermediate columns then list all the possible seat combinations for that date, and the previous seats assigned for that date, and produce a filtered list of available seats for that date, which is then sorted.
4. The first available seat for that date is then displayed.
5. As additional info, the full list of available/unassigned seats is displayed in the adjacent column.
6. The agent selects that same date on the customer's row (data validation restricts dates to those in the PerformanceDates), and enters the available Row and Seat.

Note that there are lots of different ways of handling this data.  It might be simpler if the Row and Seat columns were merged, and just treated as one combined value.  And is the year significant in the dates?  It might clean up the display a bit if the year was retained but hidden, for example.

I can't think of a data validation way to limit the possible Row and Seat values on a customer row to just the available seats, without using code.

Let me know if this is useful, and I can maybe do some cleanup of the formulas, and try to eliminate the intermediate columns.

[image]